# Why cannot evaluate a fix-defined expression with an abstract value in Coq?

Tags: coq

I need to prove a theorem:

```
Theorem t : forall x, (fix f (n : nat) : nat := n) x = x.
```

An informal proof will be as simple as

```
f is an identity function. So the result is the same as the input.
```

If I use `simpl` after `intro x`, nothing will change. Coq doesn't try evaluate the fix-function with abstract value x. Howeverz if I make an inductive analysis on x, Coq will automatically evaluate the left-hand-side of the equation and reduce it to `0` and `S x`.

Why does Coq forbid me to evaluate the fix-function with an abstract value x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`simpl` (and all of the other computation tactics) apply conversion rules. Since your goal is an equality, you could directly use `reflexivity` if your terms were convertible. But `(fix f (n : nat) : nat := n) x` and `x` are not convertible.

The rule for reducing `fix` is iota conversion. It's described in the [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual006.html#sec214) (chapter 4 “Calculus of Inductive Constructions”, §4.5.5 “Fixpoint definitions”, under “Reduction rule”). The reduction rule requires that the argument starts with a constructor. In general, this is needed to ensure termination. There's an example in the manual that's similar to yours:

> The following is not a conversion but can be proved after a case
>   analysis.
>
> ```
> Coq < Goal forall t:tree, sizet t = S (sizef (sont t)).
> Coq < Coq < 1 subgoal
>
>   ============================
>    forall t : tree, sizet t = S (sizef (sont t))
>
> Coq < reflexivity. (** this one fails **)
> Toplevel input, characters 0-11:
> > reflexivity.
> > ^^^^^^^^^^^
> Error: Impossible to unify "S (sizef (sont t))" with "sizet t".
>
> Coq < destruct t.
> 1 subgoal
>
>   f : forest
>   ============================
>    sizet (node f) = S (sizef (sont (node f)))
>
> Coq < reflexivity.
> No more subgoals.
> ```

The equality you want to prove is in fact some form of extensionality. Coq does not have extensionality as a primitive rule, it can be derived when types are explicit. Destructing the explicit `nat` argument does exactly that: let you prove this extensionality property. It's fairly common in Coq developments to prove this kind of extensionality lemma.

```
Theorem t : forall x, (fix f (n : nat) : nat := n) x = x.
Proof.
  destruct x; reflexivity.
Qed.
```