# What causes `fix` to appear after unfolding?

Tags: coq

After unfolding everything I can in an attempt to get rid of symbols I don't want in my induction hypothesis, I am left with:

```
X: Type
test: X -> bool
x: X
l: list X
IHl: (fix existsb
         (X : Type) (test : X -> bool) 
         (l : list X) {struct l} : bool :=
         fold orb (map test l) false) X test l =
      negb
        ((fix forallb
            (X : Type) (test : X -> bool)
            (l : list X) {struct l} : bool :=
            fold andb (map test l) true) X
           (fun x : X => negb (test x)) l)
```

The two fixpoints which wind up embedded should be evaluated as far as I can see since I have already `intros`'ed their parameters; and if they simply were evaluated with their parameters, my `IHl` would be perfect.

I am not clear on why these won't evaluate in this case. As the example is from logical foundations, I haven't provided more of my solution hoping that it's enough to ask what tactic can I apply to `IHl` to cause coq to actually do the rewrite with the arguments that I am looking for.

Comment: Did you define `existsb` and `forallb` yourself? It seems to me like there is no need to use `fix`, as there is no recursion involved in their definition since you relied on `fold` instead. If you replace your `Fixpoint` by a `Definition`, all should be well. If you wanted to do a "real" recursive definition, then you should not rely on `fold`, and the proof you are trying to do by induction would feel much more natural.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Meven. The book specifies Fixpoint for these functions which is needless and much more complicated than defining them in terms of fold. I defined only the bodies.

However, rewriting them as Definition makes my proof script fail at an earlier point, so I didn't spend time exploring that to understand why `simpl` fails to simplify them when they are definitions. I'll check out that approach again now that I have it working via `destruct` to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I was able to get it working with all definitions, which involves more unfolding to get simplifications that happen automatically when the exact same things are defined as fixpoint. Once I had that working I was able to shorten the proof script. I think it is debatable which proof is more understandable - a huge weakness of `coq` in my view - both scripts are relatively impenetrable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I don't really understand but it seems my case is fundamentally similar to this question:

[Why cannot evaluate a fix-defined expression with an abstract value in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604913/why-cannot-evaluate-a-fix-defined-expression-with-an-abstract-value-in-coq)

It seems that the workaround is to `destruct l` in order to ensure that the cases all start with a constructor, which then eliminates the fixpoints in two redundant cases that make the proof more or less immediate from there.

A post to enlighten me better about why there is no way to get one level of substitution here would be great, as I can't see any reason not to have a tactic that will apply in this circumstance.